# VSTO: How do I cast a mailitem as a form?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

If I have an Outlook.MailItem how can I get the Location, Width and Height of this?

Also I need to "disable" the entire Outlook.MailItem form - how do I do this?

I want to show a centered "modal" dialog (just a Windows.Forms.Form) over this MailItem without it actually being modal.

Thanks

Update (more explaining)...

When a user clicks "Send" on a mail, I want to check it for large files before sending and if the file size are too big, then I want to show a "Files are too big, do you want to zip them" dialog. The dialog must be centered to the mail form and disable the mail form (like a dialog would) without freezing outlook.

Comment: So you are trying to replace an Outlook inspector? Why not simply close it?

Comment: Please see my update above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to disable the default form in Outlook.

For example, the [Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865989.aspx) event of the MailItem class which is fired when an instance of the parent object is being opened in an Inspector. The `Cancel` parameter passed to the event handler allows to abort the default action. If the event procedure sets this argument to True, the open operation is not completed and the inspector is not displayed.
When this event occurs, the Inspector object is initialized but not yet displayed. The Open event differs from the Read event in that Read occurs whenever the user selects the item in a view that supports in-cell editing as well as when the item is being opened in an inspector.

Also you may consider using Outlook form region. The Replacement-all layout allows to override the whole inspector window. See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Comment: please see my update above - sry for not being clear enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do anything with the form? Process the Application.ItemSend event, display the prompt if necessary, and cancel the submission process if you need to.

Comment: Because in some circumstances I need the user to make a choice before sending the mail - like if files are too big and I have to ask if the user is sure that the recipient can receive such huge mails or if the user clicks a button to export the mail to our CRM system, and the mail is already exported - then I need to warn the user.

Comment: Ok, so you can display a dialog box with the active inspector as the parent window, can't you?

Comment: Nope - I get this error:  'Public Shared Overloads Function Show(owner As IWin32Window, text As String) As DialogResult': Argument matching parameter 'owner' narrows from 'Inspector' to 'IWin32Window'

Comment: So you are having problems retrieving the inspector HWND?